# Do console commands on Skyrim Anniversary Edition disable Steam achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Now that console says that some commands will disable achievements after that Anniversary update, what, if any, will disable achievements?

Answer (score 4):

I can't find anything but speculations, as the Anniversary Edition is pretty recent, but here's a (sort of) solution:

Find an achievement that is very easy to get. Make a save right before you get it, use some random commands from the console and see if the achievement pops afterwards. If it doesn’t, you can reload the save you made from before.

By the way, there should be mods that re-enable achievements.

Comment: one achievement that is easy to cheat/get/test, is to give yourself 100000 septims